# Adding objects to ArrayList - got n-times last found object

Tags: java, arraylist

I,ve got a problem with my project. I'm trying to add 16 objects (buildings) to ArrayList when I'm reading map for my game from file. After all, I get 16 same objects (last found building on map) and I dont know why...

Creating ArrayList in class Game:

```
public static ArrayList<Building> buildingList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Reading map (class Map) [Terrain goes to Array, and building if found, goes to ArrayList]:

```
private void readBuilding(Terrain objct, int x, int y) {
    System.out.format("Dodaję: ");
    //Czerwone centrum dowodzenia
    if(objct.getSSX() == 1 && objct.getSSY() == 3) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 1, 1);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Czerwona miasto
    if(objct.getSSX() == 2 && objct.getSSY() == 3) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 2, 1);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Czerwona fabryka
    if(objct.getSSX() == 3 && objct.getSSY() == 3) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 3, 1);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Niebieskie centrum dowodzenia
    if(objct.getSSX() == 1 && objct.getSSY() == 4) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 1, 2);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Niebieska fabryka
    if(objct.getSSX() == 2 && objct.getSSY() == 4) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 2, 2);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Niebieskie miasto
    if(objct.getSSX() == 3 && objct.getSSY() == 4) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 3, 2);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Niczyje miasto
    if(objct.getSSX() == 4 && objct.getSSY() == 3) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 3, 0);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
    //Niczyja fabryka
    if(objct.getSSX() == 4 && objct.getSSY() == 4) {
        Building b = new Building(x, y, 2, 0);
        b.writeBuilding();
        Game.buildingList.add(b);
    }
}


private void createMap() {
    map = new Terrain[40][22];
    String[] fields = csvFileContent.split(";");
    int x, y;
    int fieldNo = 0;

    for(y = 0; y < 22; y++) {
        for(x = 0; x < 40; x++) {            
            Terrain objct = new Terrain();
            objct.setSSX(Integer.parseInt(fields[fieldNo].substring(0,2)));
            objct.setSSY(Integer.parseInt(fields[fieldNo].substring(2,4)));
            if(objct.getSSY() > 2) {
                readBuilding(objct, x, y);
                objct.setSSX(3);
                objct.setSSY(1);
            }
            fieldNo++;
            map[x][y] = objct;
        }
    }
    System.out.format("Elementow: %d\n",Game.buildingList.size());
    for(Building b : Game.buildingList) {
        b.writeBuilding();
    }
}
```

Rendering map on screen (clas Map):

```
public void render(Graphics graphics, Game game) {
    int x, y;
    //System.out.println("Budynkow: " + game.getBuildingList().size());
    for(y = 0; y < 22; y++) {
        for(x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
            field = ss.grabImage(map[x][y].getSSX(), map[x][y].getSSY(), 32, 32);
            graphics.drawImage(field, x*32, y*32, null);
        }
    }
    Iterator<Building> it = Game.buildingList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) { 
        Building b = it.next();
        field = ss.grabImage(b.getSSX(), b.getSSY(), 32, 32);
        graphics.drawImage(field, b.getX()*32, b.getY()*32, null);
    }
}
```

I've also trying to iterate on List like this:

```
for(Building b : Game.buildingList) {
    field = ss.grabImage(b.getSSX(), b.getSSY(), 32, 32);
    graphics.drawImage(field, b.getX()*32, b.getY()*32, null);
}
```

And its also not work.

Method in class Map:

```
b.writeBuilding();
```

gives me right fields value when im writing it to NetBeans console, but it adding all the time the same.

Class terrain:

```
package game;

class Terrain {
private int ssX;
private int ssY;
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean occupied;
private boolean crossable;

Terrain() {
    this.occupied = false;
}

public void setSSX(int ssX) {
    this.ssX = ssX;
}

public void setSSY(int ssY) {
    this.ssY = ssY;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getSSX() {
    return ssX;
}

public int getSSY() {
    return ssY;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setCrossable() {
    if(ssX == 2 && ssY == 2) {
        this.crossable = false;
    } else {
        if(ssX >= 6 && ssX <= 11) {
            if(ssY >= 1 && ssY <= 2) {
                this.crossable = false;
            } else {
                this.crossable = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Class Building:

```
package game;

public class Building {
private static int owner;
private static int type;
private static int x;
private static int y;
private static int ssX;
private static int ssY;

public Building(int x, int y, int type, int owner) {
this.owner = owner;
this.type = type;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;

if(this.owner == 0) {
    if(this.type == 2) {
    this.ssX = 4;
    this.ssY = 4;
    } else if(this.type == 3) {
    this.ssX = 4;
    this.ssY = 3;
    }
} else if(this.owner == 1) {
    if(this.type == 1) {
    this.ssX = 1;
    this.ssY = 3;
    } else if(this.type == 2) {
    this.ssX = 2;
    this.ssY = 3;
    } else if(this.type == 3) {
    this.ssX = 3;
    this.ssY = 3;
    }
} else if(this.owner == 2) {
    if(this.type == 1) {
    this.ssX = 1;
    this.ssY = 4;
    } else if(this.type == 2) {
    this.ssX = 2;
    this.ssY = 4;
    } else if(this.type == 3) {
    this.ssX = 3;
    this.ssY = 4;
    }
}
}

public int getX() {
return x;
}
public int getY() {
return y;
}
public int getSSX() {
return ssX;
}
public int getSSY() {
return ssY;
}

public void writeBuilding() {
System.out.format("Owner: %d Type: %d X: %d Y: %d SSX: %d SSY %d\n"
    ,this.owner,this.type,this.x,this.y,this.ssX,this.ssY);
}
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for help. ;)

Comment: "any ideas" <-- no. You say what happens but not what you actually expect.

Comment: I assume he gets 16 same objects, but expects 16 different objects

Comment: My mistake! Sorry. Of course I'm expecting 16 differernt objects on list. I have 16 building on map, with different X and Y positions. And differetn ssX, ssY (graphics). But I'm getting 16 times last found building. And it renders 16 times in same place on map...

Comment: What happens if you just print out the buildings to `System.out` when you iterate through the list when rendering? Use (or even override) the `toString` method! This could well be a buffering error in the rendering part of the game...

Comment: When I'm printing building before adding it to List it's OK. After adding all, ther's 16 same objects. For example: I'm creating oject with fields x: 5 y: 5, adding it to list, and on list, it has x: 2 y: 4. And every single object added to List have same values on each fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building uses static fields, which get overwritten each time you initalize an object, so all will be equal in the end.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

The point about static is that it is not instance, but classlevel variable, meaning that no matter how many times you create a new object (new Buildink(..,..);), those variables will be shared between each instance.